# What is cookie with key "ebNewBandWidth"? Where is it set?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies

Over the past 3 days I've been getting the "Disallowed Key Characters" error from CodeIgniter's Input class. I've found that this is resulting from CI checking for valid global cookie keys in the $_COOKIE array. The particular keys tripping the alert are below (where asianfanfics.com is the site I'm working on):

ebNewBandWidth__www_asianfanfics_com=277%3A1357053922099;expires=Wed,_01_Jan_2014_15:25:24_GMT;_path=/;_domain=_www_asianfanfics_com

ebPanelFrequency__www_asianfanfics_com=\"\";expires=Tue,_01_Jan_2013_15:43:39_GMT;_path=/;_domain=_www_asianfanfics_com

So if `$_COOKIE[$key] = $value`, `$key` is not passing CI's check and `$value` is always empty. When inspecting that cookie on Chrome's cookie inspector, I see that it is set for the www subdomain and under expires, instead of a date, it says "session".

The only other question on SO relating to this is due to someone using the jQuery Tabs plugin which I'm not using.

**Does anyone know what could be setting this cookie?**

Comment: I have just discovered this problem on a site I manage thats built using CodeIgniter and uses LinkedIn. It appears that the cookie is malformed and the whole string has been pushed into the key.
No closer to finding the cause though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the name of the cookies (starting with *`ebNewBandWidth`*  and *`ebPanelFrequency`*), you might want to ask LinkedIn if their servers have injected some code into client resources served by your server or otherwise connected to your website or domainname it is served from that has created these cookies:

> LinkedIn Corporation
>   Attn: Privacy Policy Issues
>   2029 Stierlin Court
>   Mountain View,CA 94043
>   USA
>
> http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=privacy_policy

Might because generally everybody can set everything which is acccepted as a valid cookie name from the browser requesting with such cookie request headers.

*Session* in that cookie means, it will expire when the browser is closed.

The rest looks like that Codeigniter is dropping that cookie for some reason. Probably only a pre-caution.

Any HTTP client can send any kind of cookie request headers to your server, so there is nothing you can do against that.

The cookie is always set by the user-agent, at least the cookie in the request that is causing the error (what goes into `$_COOKIE`).

Which process originally has set this specific cookie can not be said by the name of the cookie only. Any process can create any kind of cookie header, and the cookie seems at least valid enough to make the browser send it with the requests.

Probably Codeigniter needs some fix or setting here so you can make use of such keys, e.g. you might want to disable that (in your case useless?) check.

Comment: Thanks. For now I've extended CI's input class to ignore cookie key errors but I'm uneasy modifying core class functionality. This hasn't happened in the 3 years the code has been running so not sure what could be causing it now. So you're saying this is being set by the user's browser and not by the server? Can I safely ignore this cookie for now?

Comment: I can not tell you whether or not you can safely ignore that cookie. Probably yes, probably not.

Comment: Just saw your edit. I've seen some other websites say they have cookies with that key (Infiniti) but still not sure why mine would all of a sudden be affected. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Are you using some linkedin javascript widget? Something like vote for my post, comment it, make friends, like or whatever "social" stuff?

Comment: I have Google+, FB likes, and Twitter. I've seen the cookie path for that problem cookie set to pages that don't have these widgets though so I didn't think it would be it but I'll try disabling them. Is that the sort of cookie that would be set by PHP's session process like session_start()? I have a third party ticket board that uses PHP sessions (my application does not).

Comment: No that is not PHP's session cookie. Contact the vendor of the third party ticket board if they are making use of such cookies. Ask them that they provide a full list of all names of cookies used by their board. Tell them you need to know that because of privacy reasons with the countries legislation of your website's visitors. Asking that way might reveal more for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MediaMind formerly EyeBlaster (hence eb prefix to cookies) is behind these cookies.  Their service is widely used by banner adservices, so they may well be involved indirectly by a service your site uses.  The infiniti cookie page referred to above links them to ebNewBandWidth.